# Enzyme .eq() or .index()?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

Enzyme has a cheerio-like set of selector functions, but it doesn't seem to have `.eq()` or `.index()`. I couldn't find a super-specific set of functions it does implement anywhere in their documentation.

Is there a function like `.eq()` or `.index()` I can use to get a specific element at a specific index.

`:nth-child()` doesn't appear to be implemented and `.get()` unwraps it, which I don't particularly want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`.at()`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/at.html)

> Returns a wrapper around the node at a given index of the current wrapper.

Comment: Thanks. Stumbled upon the page I was looking for too: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/GLOSSARY.html#wrapper